# Most popular block ciphers

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design

Which block (cipher) algorithms are the most popular and most used today?

What parameter values (block length, key length) are now considered standard (safe).

Comment: I often see apps using either `AES-GCM-256` or `AES-CTR-256`.

Comment: Standard depends on the country, USA NIST, The European Union Agency for Cybersecurity (ENISA), etc. If we consider only the internet then TLS defines the usages...